# multer, node js, upload photo

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

i want to upload some photo to my server, i'am cheating on my friends code. but when i console the req (`console.log(req)`) the result is diffrent. i cant `console.log(req.file)` if i write that code the result is undifined, and i must change with `req.files.photo` but in my friends code is success with the result without change to `req.files.photo`

this my routes and multer config (same with my friend code) :

```
const multerDiskStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './assets/images/');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        const originalName = file.originalname;
        const nameArr = originalName.split('.');
        var extension = '';
        if(nameArr.length > 1) {
            extension = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];
        }

        cb(null, file.filename+'-'+Date.now()+'.'+extension);
    }
});

const multerUpload = multer({storage: multerDiskStorage});

router.patch('/upload', multerUpload.single('photo'), async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const photo = req.file;
        console.log(photo)
        const photoPerson = 'http://localhost:3000/api/person/getphoto/'+photo.filename;
        console.log('foto', photo);
        if(!photo) {
            res.status(400).json({'message': 'Picture cannot be empety'});
            return
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({
        'status': 'ERROR',
        'messages': err.message,
        'values': {},
        })
    }
});
```

the result from my code is :

```
foto {
  photo: {
    name: 'apeng 1.jpg',
    data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 11 21 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 12 01 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 04 1b 00 00 01 01 00 03 00 00 00 01 05 dc 00 00 01 02 00 03 ... 700959 more bytes>,
    size: 701009,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    md5: '4e0774cd7159716b00c8e89fe4b8dee4',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}
```

and the result of my friend code is:

```
foto {
  fieldname: 'photo',
  originalname: 'desain.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: './assets/images/',
  filename: 'undefined-1618923348508.jpeg',
  path: 'assets\\images\\undefined-1618923348508.jpeg',
  size: 45544
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your middleware. I think you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload. It catches your photo before multer